# I want to create a function that observes a property then calls a function once the property reaches 100

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire

My goal is to refresh the view once the percentageChages() reaches 100:

The value:

```
  this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
```

The function I want to create :

```
refreshView(){
Once this.uploadPercent == 100;
  window.location.reload();
}
```

A standrad loop seemed too resource intesive for this, something light would be nice.

Comment: If you are using angular, then try working with observables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of rxjs and Observables (comes built in with angular).

For instance instantiate uploadPecent to be:

```
uploadPercent = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
```

Then you can set the value of this similarly to before with:

```
uploadPercent.next(task.percentageChanges());
```

Then all you have to do is set up pipeline like so (could do this inside the ngOnInit lifecycle hook):

```
this.uploadPercent.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroy$)
).subscribe(x => {
  if (x >= 100) {
    window.location.reload();
  }
});
```

Where destroy$ is instantiated to:

```
destroy$ = new Subject<void>();
```

And the destroy pattern is completed in ngOnDestroy (this prevents memory leaks from the subscription):

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next();
  this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

You can find out more about rxjs from the official docs here:
https://rxjs.dev/guide/overview
Or this website is also good for info:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/